# How to make a Dart paper-button inside a <template> visible?

Tags: dart, polymer

I want to use a Polymer `paper-button`. It gets used on the top layer of the program, e.g. not inside another `PolymerElement`.

How can I register an `onClick` or `onTap` handler for this `paper-button`? There exists no such method in the `PaperButton` class and a declaration in the HTML file as an attribute is not possible outside the scope of a `PolymerElement` derived class.

Except you use a `<template>` directive. The `<template>`version works for me with a normal `<button>` but I can not figure out how to get a `<paper-button>` displayed!

Here is the simplest possible code to show the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Paper Button</title>

  <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_button.html">
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <template is="auto-binding-dart">
    <paper-button id="mybutton" on-tap="{{buttonTap}}">Button</paper-button>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart">
    import 'dart:html';
    import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
    import 'package:template_binding/template_binding.dart';

    main() {
      initPolymer().run(() {
        Polymer.onReady.then((_) {
          var template = document.querySelector('template');
          templateBind(template).model = new MyModel();
        });
      });
    }

    class MyModel extends Observable {
      buttonTap() => print('Clicked!');
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change this from `paper-button` to `button` **and** remove the import statement for the `paper-button` then it works as expected. But how to do it with a `paper-button` or any kind of polymer element for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

The error message you mentioned in the comment using the code suggested below

> The first line creates a run-time error
>
> > NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'model='.
>
> The second proposal creates the error
>
> > Exception: >Uncaught Error: type 'TemplateElement' is not a subtype of type 'AutoBindingElement' of 'template'.

indicate that `querySelector('template')` doesn't return the `<template is="auto-binding-dart">` but some other `template` element instead (the imported `paper-button` element).

Using a different selector (for example with an id) instead solves the problem.

#### Old

This looks fine but this one line seems wrong to me (but if it works for Button it should work for `paper-button` as well.

```dart
templateBind(template).model = new MyModel();
```

Instead

```dart
template.model = new MyModel();
```

Great!
should do
or

```dart
AutoBindingElement template = document.querySelector('template');
template.model = new MyModel();
```

to prevent a hint about a non-existing `model` setter.

You shouldn't need this import (only in your own elements).

```dart
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
```

I never use inline script. Maybe this causes an issue.

Comment: The first line creates a run-time error `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'model='`. The second proposal creates the error `Exception: Uncaught Error: type 'TemplateElement' is not a subtype of type 'AutoBindingElement' of 'template'.`

Comment: Maybe you get another template element (the one from the imported `paper-button`?). Can you try to assign an `id` to the `template` and change the selector so it uses the id instead of the tag name?

Comment: Yes, the hint with the template from the imported `paper-button` nailed it! Using an `id` to retrieve the template solves the problem!